# Given a triangle with a and b as the length of two of its sides, what should the angle between a and the third side be so that the triangle is right?

Tags: geometry

My most likely wrong solution:

Let $(x = 0, y = 0)$ and $(x = a, y = 0)$ be two vertices of the triangle. This is the side with the length $a$. The equation $y = \sqrt{b^2-x^2}$ creates a semicircle with a radius of $b$ around the $(x = 0, y = 0)$ vertex, and $y = (a-x)\tan{\theta}$ makes a line that passes through the $(x = a, y = 0)$ vertex. Connecting a point where the semicircle and the line collide to the center of the semicircle, the vertex $(x = 0, y = 0)$ creates our triangle. The angle between the third side and the side with the length $a$ is $\theta$. For the triangle to be right angled, the line must collide with the semicircle in only one point. Defining $q$ as $\tan{\theta}$ we have: $$\sqrt{b^2-x^2}=(a-x)q$$ $$b^2-x^2 = (a-x)^2q^2$$
$$b^2-x^2=q^2a^2-2q^2ax+q^2x^2$$
$$(q^2+1)x^2-2q^2ax+q^2a^2-b^2=0$$
Using the quadratic formula we can calculate $x$, but we know that the semicircle and the line collide in only one point, so $\Delta$ must be zero.
$$\Delta = 4q^4a^2-4(q^2+1)(q^2a^2-b^2)$$
$$\Delta = 4q^4a^2-4q^4a^2-4q^2a^2+4q^2b^2+4b^2$$
$$\Delta=4q^2(b^2-a^2)+4b^2=0$$
$$4q^2(b^2-a^2)=-4b^2$$
$$q^2 = \frac{-b^2}{b^2-a^2}$$
$$\tan{\theta}=q=\sqrt{\frac{-b^2}{b^2-a^2}}$$
$$\theta=arctan{\sqrt{\frac{-b^2}{b^2-a^2}}}$$

But plugging in $a = 1$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}$ I get $$\theta=arctan{-\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}}}}=-\frac{\pi}{6}$$

But the correct answer is $\frac{\pi}{6}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $b=1/2$ and $a=1$ then $-b^2/(b^2-a^2)=-1/4/(-3/4) = 1/3$. Why did you add a
negative sign in $\arctan - \sqrt{\frac{1/4}{3/4}}$?

Comment: $y = (a-x)\tan{\theta}$ does not make a line that passes through the $(x = a, y = 0)$ vertex unless $ a=0$.

Comment: @Narasimham could you explain further please? Plugging in x in the equation, we get $y= (a-a) tan{\theta}=0$, doesn’t it pass through the (x=a, y=0) point?

Comment: Notice that $ y=(a-x) \tan \theta $ is in $ C-m x $  form and unless $a$ vanishes the straight line does not pass through the origin.

Comment: @Narasimham $y=(a-x)\tan\theta$ may not pass through the origin, but it passes through the $(x,y) = (a,0)$ vertex.

Comment: Please note the line joins $ (0,a \tan \theta), (0,a)$ in the first quadrant

Comment: Sorry the typo, it should be $(0,a \tanθ),(a,0)$ in the first quadrant !

Answer (score 1):

In a right triangle the
sum of the squares of the sides adjacent to the right angle
is the square of the length of the opposite side. So if this
is your case (which you did not specify), the length of the opposite side
is $c=\sqrt(a^2+b^2)$ and the angle given by $\tan\theta=a/b$.
If the right angle is opposite to $a$, the length
is $c=\sqrt(a^2-b^2)$, and the angle $\sin\theta = b/a$.
If the right angle is opposite to $b$, $c=\sqrt(b^2-a^2)$ and $\theta=90^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

The third side will be √(a²+b²).
Now use cosines rule for the angle between first and third side
Let first side be 'a' and side b is opposite to angle theta

costheta = (a²+a²+b²-b²)/(2a√(a²+b²))
Now find theta in terms of a and b.
Hope this helped!!

Comment: This is a way to find one possible $\theta$, but in my opinion quite indirect. You picked the angle between sides $a,b$ to be $90^\circ$, so the angle $\theta$ opposite side $b$ satisfies $$\tan\theta = \frac ba$$. (And this is not the case that OP was considering)